# I need to install pyinstaller from pip but it keeps giving me these errors.I dont know how to fix them. i tried with and without a proxy

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

**Try number 1 (without proxy)**

```
C:\Users\sanchsba\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts>pip install pyinstaller
```

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/pyinstaller/
>   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/pyinstaller/
>   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/pyinstaller/
>   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/pyinstaller/
>   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/pyinstaller/
>   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyinstaller (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyinstaller

**Try number 2 (with proxy)**

```
C:\Users\sanchsba\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts>pip install pyinstaller --proxy sfl-hza-prx-02.schaeffler.com:8080
```

> Collecting pyinstaller
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/c9/0b44b2ea87ba36395483a672fddd07e6a9cb2b8d3c4a28d7ae76c7e7e1e5/PyInstaller-3.5.tar.gz
>     Installing build dependencies ... error
>     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>      command: 'C:\Users\sanchsba\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\sanchsba\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\sanchsba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g2g_mrrb\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
>          cwd: None
>     Complete output (7 lines):
>     WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/setuptools/
>     WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/setuptools/
>     WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/setuptools/
>     WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/setuptools/
>     WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/setuptools/
>     ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
>     ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
>
> ---
>
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\sanchsba\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\sanchsba\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\sanchsba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g2g_mrrb\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Your network is not working. Do you have internet access?

Comment: yes i do have internet connection.i know there is a firewall in my office computers though? would that affect ? isnt that what the proxy is for ? , sorry i am very new to python any help is appreciated . is there a way to make this work despite the firewall?